# Finding the IP address of an ssh connection made in the past

Tags: debian, ssh

A few weeks ago I made a few ssh connections from my home PC to my college PC and the other way around. Currently I am sitting at my home PC and I am trying to figure out what was the college PC IP address. Any idea where I could find some clues?

I scanned the log files and bash history, but there was nothing obvious there.

I am running Debian Testing.

Comment: For future reference, don't use ssh with an IP address: define an alias with a meaningful name in `~/.ssh/config`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're lucky, the IP address of the visited hosts can be obtained from `~/.ssh/known_hosts`

Comment: `~/.ssh/known_hosts` doesn't seem to be human-readable and I can't figure out which bit of it would correspond to an IP address :(

Comment: What does `cat known_hosts | cut -d, -f1` give you? It gives you anything in front of the first comma, which seems to contain this information.

Comment: @Grzenio Host names in `known_hosts` are hashed for privacy. You can turn this off from `~/.ssh/config` (`HashKnownHosts no`), but it's too late for old connections. If you suspect that a name or IP address is in there but aren't sure, run `ssh-keygen -F tentative-host-name`.

Answer (score 4):

`last -n 20 -a`*`user`*

`-n` for the 20 most recent logins
`-a` to have IP at end of line (useful if ipv6)

*user* to filter the username you want ...

Answer (score 0):

A very crude way would be (If it works at all)

```
history | grep ssh
```

Comment: This will only show the last 1000 or so shell-command, so this will probably not help him.

Comment: Yeah, checked this one before asking the question :(